# php wildcard characters in filename

Tags: php

In a PHP while loop, I have the following:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM stock ORDER BY partnumber");
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $id = $row["id"];
        $partnumber = $row["partnumber"];
        $description = $row["description"];
        $price = $row["listprice"];
        $availability = $row["availability"];
        $image = "path/$partnumber.jpg";
        if(!file_exists($image)) {      //substitute image if one does not exist
            $image = "path/no-image.jpg";
        }
```

When displaying the images in a table, I have:

```
<a href="product.php?id='.$partnumber.'"><img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$partnumber.'" /></a>
```

It works ok with exact matches.
The problem is, many of the images contain lower case x in the filename as a character wildcard.
How can I get these image filenames containing x to display with the partnumbers containing explicit characters in their filenames?

Example filename:  AB2Dxxx.jpg 
Example partnumber:  AB2DTUV

Comment: You need examples of the images with `x` and part numbers that should match.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that there are wildcard characters in a file's name. Why would that be the case?

Comment: The filenames have x in them because the image is good for more than one partnumber.  No sense making many images that are all graphically identical.  That would be a waste of storage space.

Comment: Storage is cheap - developing a workaround may be more expensive than just using up a few extra MB on the disk.

Comment: I am dealing with over 1000 images where many have the wildcard characters.  If there was an image for every partnumber, there would be several thousand to deal with.  A lot of time and expense would be needed to produce all those individual images.  My time is cheaper than photographers, or engineers making 3D renderings.

Comment: is it consistently `ABCDxxx`, and are there always three `x` chars, or is it any instance, e.g. `ABCDxxx, ABxxxxx, ABxxDxx`?

Comment: You need to make the image URL point to a script that finds the wildcards in the filename, scans the directory looking for a match, then returns the contents of that file.

Comment: Add another column to the table with the filename of the image. Then multiple partnumbers can point to the same image filename.

Comment: Or use symbolic links in the filesystem. `ln -s AB2Dxxx.jpg AB2DTUV.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help - I've had to adapt it to run locally, but it uses `glob` and assumes that the wildcards are all at the end of the string, so the filename can step back until a match is found.

The execution path has a folder called `images`, which will contain our theoretical part images.  In lieu of a database, I've defined a simple key/value array containing my test results (it looks like you only rely on the partnumber, so that's all I've defined...).

The `images` directory contains two files: `ABCDEF.jpg` and `ABCxxx.jpg`.

```
$parts = array( array( "partnumber"=> "ABCDEF" ), 
                array( "partnumber"=> "ABDCEF" ), 
                array( "partnumber"=> "ABCDDD" ) );

foreach($parts as $part) {

    $partnumber = $part["partnumber"];
    $next_pn = $partnumber;
    $pn_len = strlen($partnumber);
    echo $partnumber." is the part number<br>-------------<br>";
    while(strlen($next_pn) > 0 )
    {

        $image = null;
        foreach (glob("images/".$partnumber."*.jpg", GLOB_NOSORT) as $filename) {
           $image = $filename;
            echo $filename . " matches " . $partnumber."<br>";

        }
        if($image) {
            echo "<br>";
            break;
        }

        $next_pn = substr($next_pn, 0,  -1);
        $partnumber = str_pad($next_pn, $pn_len, "x");

    }


}
```

This outputs

```
ABCDEF is the part number
-------------
images/ABCDEF.jpg matches ABCDEF

ABDCEF is the part number
-------------
ABCDDD is the part number
-------------
images/ABCxxx.jpg matches ABCxxx
```

As you can see, it will basically take a filename and check for a match - if none is found, it takes off a character and replaces it with an `x`, then checks again.  In this case:

- ABCDEF matches `ABCDEF.jpg` instantly;
- ABDCEF doesn't match any of the files, and;
- ABCDDD matches `ABCxxx.jpg` on the fourth loop (first checks for `ABCDDD`, second `ABCDDx`, third `ABCDxx`, fourth matches on `ABCxxx`).

It isn't perfect and might need a bit more work, but it seems like it would do what you're looking to do.

P.S. `glob` has a lot of options - I've used `NOSORT` as a flag which tends to help it run a bit quicker when there are lots of files to hunt through.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php